# WebBrowserでアクセスしたサイトのモーダルを消すためにコントロールできるようにするにはどうしたらいいでしょう？

Tags: c#, visual-studio

## 概要

アクセスすると特定のソフトをダウンロードしてほしい旨がモーダルで表示されるサイトがあります。
そのモーダルを開発者ツールで見てみると

```
<div id="hoge">
  <div id="hoge2" title="close"></div>
  <img>
</div>
```

のような形でアクセス先のHTMLに追加されます。

そのサイトに

```
WebBrowser.Navigate(new Uri(url),null, null,header);
```

のようなコードで画面に遷移後、スクリプトエラーが出る（WebBrowser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;で消えはする）のとWebBrowserが持っているInnerHtmlを見てもモーダルのが追加されません。

New_Window2イベントを拾えるようにWebBrowserを拡張していますが、そちらにもモーダルのが追加されません。

どうすればハンドルできるようになるでしょうか？

※コントロールできるようになればHTMLからdivを消すかモーダル右上に表示されている「×」ボタンをクリックすれば消せるかもしれないと思っています。

※WebBrowserからでなく、人がIEからアクセスして一度モーダルを消すと表示されなくなるので、一度表示した状態を作ってアクセスできればそもそもコントロールする必要もないのかもとも思っていますが方法がわかりません。

## 動作環境

・.NET Frame Work 4.5
・Visual Studio2013

## 目的

・モーダルの下にあるログインボタンをクリックして次のページに遷移したい。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 「ハンドルできる」が何を求めているのかわかりませんでした。「ログインボタンをクリックして」もプログラムによる操作なのかユーザー操作なのか判別できませんでした。「一度モーダルを消すと表示されなくなる」のはcookieに記録されていたりしませんか？

Comment: https://teratail.com/questions/18462 マルチポスト